# How can I get my Image Slider to Autoplay with just CSS?

Tags: css, image, hover, slider, autoplay

I also want to know how I can get it to pause on hover.

I already have an image slider that scrolls across with arrows on the side I just need to know the autoplay code. I have looked around quite a bit, but all I can find is jquery or javascript something-a-rathers.

This is my first post so please let me know if I need to include something and thanks in advance.

Comment: adding code is a "MUST" on Stackoverflow , even though the rule book does't say so .

Comment: I suggest you post your working sample code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Or at least provide some codes. But here's the thing. `CSS` is used to add styles and some minor animations your `HTML`, but it is not smart to use it to override the functions that `javascript` is supposed to do. I am going to recommend to you this `CSS` Framework, it also includes image sliders, pretty customizable and dynamic. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: I added it to this, it looks completely fine for me, that preview must not work. http://jsfiddle.net/28rz2bw5/